# Android and IPv6 in Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, ipv6

I am developing an Android application and I need to use IPv6 to connect to a server.

IPv6 is enabled on the phone and I can see my local IPv6 address with `ip addr`. I can also successfully `ping6` my phone from the PC and viceversa.

But hen I try to get local addresses on Android through the Java command `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` I only get IPv4 addresses.

I also tryed to open a client socket but the line
`Socket s = new Socket(MYSERVERIPV6ADDRESS, PORT);`
always throws `java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument`.
I am sure the address is correct because I tryed with the same code on my computer and works perfectly.

It seems that IPv6 is supported by the operating system but not by the Java virtual machine. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Update: Using `Socket s = new Socket(MYSERVERIPV6ADDRESS+"/64%eth0", PORT);` throws `java.net.SocketException: Unknown host exception`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this static method in Inet6Address to get a Inet6Address object for your address,

Inet6Address getByAddress (String host, byte[] addr, int scope_id)

then use, the following socket constructor to get a socket,

Socket(InetAddress dstAddress, int dstPort).

Comment: Method Inet6Address getByAddress (String host, byte[] addr, int scope_id) is fine to get  IPv6 dest address, but with real device I get timeout but with emulator it works, so this must be networking problem. Maybe network interface parameters is needed?

Answer (score 1):

IP6 support is the choice of the vendor to include, to my understanding, support is there.

I am assuming you are testing you app in emulator. Looking at how android does networking,
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking
It's behind an IPv4 router addressed 10.0.2.1. Hence, you are not able to open a Socket using IPv6. It's all dependent if a path exists of all the routers who are IPv6 compatible from your phone to your destination.

Comment: No, I'm testing on a Galaxy SII. IPv6 is supported by the phone because I can successfully `ping6` the phone from PC and viceversa.