# IPv6 Socket on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, ipv6

I am trying to create an IPv6 TCP connection between two Android devices. However creating the socket always fails.

If I instantiate it like this:

```
Inet6Address dest = (Inet6Address) InetAddress.getByName(addressString);
Socket socket = new Socket(dest, portNumber);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to *address* (port *portNumber*): connect failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

If I instead instantiate my IPv6Address object like this:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
NetworkInterface wifiInterface = null;
while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
  NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
  if (networkInterface.getDisplayName().equals("wlan0") || networkInterface.getDisplayName().equals("eth0")) {
    wifiInterface = networkInterface;
    break;
  }
}
Inet6Address dest = Inet6Address.getByAddress(null, addressBytes, wifiInterface );
Socket socket = new Socket(dest, portNumber);
```

I get this error when calling the Socket constructor:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to *address* (port *portNumber*): connect failed: EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address)
```

This happens both on a Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean and a Nexus One with Gingerbread.

Am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to create a socket like that?

Also: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563018/android-and-ipv6-in-java) suggests using the constructor

```
Inet6Address getByAddress (String host, byte[] addr, int scope_id)
```

What would I have to use as scope_id in this case?

Comment: show us dest and portNumber variables values.

Comment: The value of addressString in the first variant would for example be "fe80::9221:55ff:fee3:3303".
The corresponding addressBytes array is [-2, -128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -110, 33, 85, -1, -2, -29, 51, 3].
For the port I am using 3109. This is supposed to be a random port that is not being used for anything else.

Comment: By chance is the router you are connected to support IPv6?

Comment: I can ping all my devices on their IPv6 address. On the Galaxy Nexus the NetworkInterface object even contains the device's IPv6 address and on the Nexus One I can at least read it from /proc/net/if_inet6. So I am pretty sure the router supports it :)

Answer (score 5):

Since your IP Address is link local, perhaps it MUST be created with a scope ID or Interface so that the OS knows what interface to bind it to.  As for specifying the scope_id, the Android docs seem somewhat lacking.  The Oracle docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) indicate that the scope ID is system specific and cannot be determined programmatically.

So, I would try using the alternate factory method where you explicitly specify the NetworkInterface you wish to use.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html#getByAddress%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.net.NetworkInterface%29) for details.  There are methods in the NetworkInterface class to discover what interfaces exist on the system.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't that the factory method I used in the second variant, which throws an only slightly different exception?

Comment: You're right!  Sorry about that!  How did you find the NetworkInterface object that you used in that attempt?

Comment: I iterate through all the available interfaces and select the one I need by name and I verified that I am indeed getting back the correct interface. 
I added the code in the original post for clarity.