# Android Lollipop (5.1.1) - How to use IPV6 address when creating a socket connection

Tags: android, linux, sockets, ipv6, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm putting together some proof of concept code to send a string over a wifi connection to a linux server.  I managed this when using an IPV4 address but now I am having difficulty adding support for IPV6.  The error reports that my IPV6 address isn't valid.

I did find this SO thread... [IPv6 Socket on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421962/ipv6-socket-on-android) but that is from years ago.  Perhaps things are done differently now?  (I've noticed that 3 years is a long, long time in Android).

Here's the function I'm trying to get working (I've taken out a bunch of unrelated code to make it look a bit less cluttered)...

```
private void SocketTest()
{
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    try
    {
        Inet6Address ipv6_addr = null;
        NetworkInterface nif = null;

        nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("wlan0");

        if(nif != null)
        {
            //HOSTNAME is "fred"
            //HOST_IPV6_ADDR is "fe80::7e5c:f8ff:fe3b:e7c3"
            //ERROR occurs on next line...
            ipv6_addr = Inet6Address.getByAddress(HOSTNAME, HOST_IPV6_ADDR.getBytes(), nif);
        }

        if(ipv6_addr != null)
            socket = new Socket(ipv6_addr, 12345);

        //socket = new Socket("192.168.88.184", 12345);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("in SocketTest()\n");
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
//[... unrelated stuff ...]
}
```

I get the following error during the call to Inet6Address.getByAddress(...):

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Not an IPv6 address: [102, 101, 56, 48 ... 99, 51]
```

Further info: this is the remote linux server's wlan0 info (it only has 1 wifi interface)...

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:5c:f8:3b:e7:c3
          inet6 addr: fe80::7e5c:f8ff:fe3b:e7c3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2453 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:108860 (106.3 KiB)  TX bytes:152518 (148.9 KiB)
```

The IPV4 version of this code worked as you would expect, the remote server is operational.  The remote server also has an IPV6 address on it's wired ethernet port and I can ssh into that IPV6 address just fine from another machine on the same wired LAN.  Ergo my code is broken.

Can someone explain what my code is doing wrong or missing out?

Sorry if this seems like a duplicate question but there doesn't seem to be much recent information on this topic as far as I can see.

---

**EDIT**

I should have used this instead of a string to hold the IPv6 address...

```
//"fe80::7e5c:f8ff:fe3b:e7c3";
    private final byte[] HOST_IPV6_ADDR = {(byte)0xfe
                                         , (byte)0x80
                                         , 0x00
                                         , 0x00
                                         , 0x00
                                         , 0x00
                                         , 0x00
                                         , 0x00
                                         , 0x7e
                                         , 0x5c
                                         , (byte)0xf8
                                         , (byte)0xff
                                         , (byte)0xfe
                                         , 0x3b
                                         , (byte)0xe7
                                         , (byte)0xc3
    };
```

Thank you `StenSoft`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[102, 101, 56, 48 ... 99, 51]` means you are passing bytes of a string `"fe80::…"`. You need to pass numeric value of the IP address, so it should start with `[-2, -128, …]` or `[0xfe, 0x80, …]`. (It's basically using string `"123"` instead of number `123`.)

You can use `InetAddress.getByName` with the string if you don't want to parse the values. IPv6 supports passing scope in the form “address%scope“, so `"fe80::7e5c:f8ff:fe3b:e7c3%wlan0"` in your case.

Comment: Ah.  I see what you mean.  I have changed my code to use a byte[] instead of string.getBytes().  However now the error continues with: **java.net.UnknownHostException: Not an IPv6 address: [-2, -128, 58, 58, 126, 92, 58, -8, -1, 58, -2, 59, 58, -25, -61]** Not sure if that's just the way the error message is printed or whether it is really interpreting these as signed values.

Comment: @Wossname IPv6 address has 16 bytes, your array has 15. You are one byte short. Java has only signed types, I will update my answer with the correct (signed) values.

Comment: @Wossname Note that the correct value for fe80::7e5c:f8ff:fe3b:e7c3 would start with `[-2, -128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126, 92, …]`

Comment: That's a bit better.  The original error has changed to something else which I'll have to figure out.  Many thanks for your assistance.