# How does android emulator connect IPV6?

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);
```

if the ip is IPV4,it can connect successfully,but if the ip is ipv6, it gets a exception as follow

```
java.net.ConnectException:failed to connect to /fe80::c64:5cff:feb5:8787 (port 9555) from /::(port): connect failed:EINVAL(Invalid argument)
```

The android emulator version is API level 28.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify `scope_id` (NetworkInterface) which is described in [Inet6Address Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html#textual-representation-of-ipv6-scoped-addresses) .

Here is similar question which might help you with implementation details how to do that:
[IPv6 Socket on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421962/ipv6-socket-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

In my tests emulator connections with IPv6 addresses work sama way, than with host with java/kotlin. If your used parameters, that seems to be used as error message ip="/fe80::c64:5cff:feb5", your must drop "/". It is pure hostname like "google.com" or pure IPv6-addresss "2a00:1450:4026:804::200e".

But IPv6 connections don't work from outside to emulator and the is no instructions how to do that. Seems that emulator gets only fake IPv6 addresses that can't be pingable from host to emulator.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my thoughts on what I think is going on:

When emulator runs, it does not connect to the developers network.  It isolates itself from that network environment.  Internally it uses a virtual router and dns to keep itself isolated. In my case, my developer network is using 192.168.50.0/24 whereas the android emulator is using 10.0.2.0/8.

I'm not able to ping either the ipv4 or ipv6 address of the emulator from the outside.  And that's because the ping command from the outside world is isolated from the android emulator network.  I can however use "adb" to issue a "ping" command to the emulators ipv4 address. Similarly I can use "adb" to issue a "ping6" command to ping the emulators ipv6 address. When using "adb" both ping commands work.  Please note, the you may notice several IPV6 addresses associated with the emulator.  I've noticed that not all of those IPV6 addresses are pingable.  I'm not totally sure why, but I'm also not sure what all those ipv6 addresses are being used for.  I've looked at the detailed InetAddress for all those addresses.  I'm not able to ping an IPV6 address if its "Link Local". I can't ping IPv6 address that are "Secondary" or "Temporary" unless it also has "DAD" enabled. Those are just observations and not necessary cause/effect related.

Going back to the original question, Lee says that he can use an ipV4 addresses in the socket command and it works.  Unfortunately we, don't know whether he is using a global or link local ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.  So what Janis B is saying might be correct.  What I noticed when I did the ping and ping6 command with the "-a" option, I got a name back for the ipv4 address and not for the ipv6 address.  That potential suggests that the cause could be related to how the emulators internal DNS works. If I recall correctly, I'm pretty sure I could use ipV4 address for my development environment for WebView on the emulator and it worked.  I never tried reaching the site using an ipv6 address. If it doesn't work, that would be analogous situation to what Lee was observing but with WebView instead of socket.  I'll get that a try, sometime in the future.